# Regular expression with & as separator

Tags: java, regex

I was given a long text in which I need to find all the text that are embedded in a pair of `&` (For example, in a text `"&hello&&bye&"`, I need to find the words `"hello"` and `"bye"`).

I try using the regex `".*&([^&])*&.*"` but it doesn't work, I don't know what's wrong with that.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: So it's everything on either side of the `&&`?

Comment: Do you HAVE to do it using regular expressions?

Comment: @CodeBlue: I think regex is the tool of choice for this kind of job. What did you have in mind instead?

Comment: Tim, a number of things come to my mind - the Scanner class or the String.split() method.

Comment: What happens if you have something like "&hello&bye&" instead of "&hello&&bye&"? Can an ampersand be used in multiple matches?'

Comment: @CodeBlue String.split takes a regex...

Comment: Ultimately I think your pattern should have been `([^&]*)` instead of having the `*` outside of the parents.

Answer (score 6):

Try this way

```
String data = "&hello&&bye&";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("&([^&]*)&").matcher(data);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

output:

```
hello
bye
```

Comment: @jackyokboy Glad you like it, but I am also interested in CorrugatedAirs comment about `"&hello&bye&"`. Could you respond and tell what results should be?

Comment: @jackyokboy:  My hope is that you don't just blindly copy and paste this into wherever you need it.  You should try to digest what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

No regex needed. Just iterate!

```
boolean started = false;
List<String> list;
int startIndex;
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i){
    if(string.charAt(i) != '&')
        continue;
    if(!started) {
        started = true;
        startIndex = i + 1;
    }
    else {
        list.add(string.substring(startIndex, i)); // maybe some +-1 here in indices
    }
    started = !started;
}
```

or use split!

```
String[] parts = string.split("&");
for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) { // every second
    list.add(parts[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for split version. Had the same idea but few minutes later :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regular expressions, here's a simple way.

```
String string = "xyz...." // the string containing "hello", "bye" etc. 


String[] tokens = string.split("&"); // this will split the string into an array 
                                     // containing tokens separated by "&"

for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
 {
     String token = tokens[i];


     if(token.length() > 0)
        { 
             // handle edge case
             if(i==tokens.length-1)
             {
                   if(string.charAt(string.length()-1) == '&')
                     System.out.println(token);
             }
             else 
              { 
                System.out.println(token);
              }
        }
 }
```

Comment: seems you will never print in "edge cases", because if conditions are true, then that tokens have length = 0

Comment: @RiaD, oh, is it because split will put a blank string as the first token when "$" is the first character?

Comment: I investigated it. Empty trailing string will be ignored, while empty first will not. Java is so Java. So, first check is unnecessary while the second is good. Or you may use negative limit to not ignore it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) http://ideone.com/ZuvUfB

Comment: Yes, you're right. The first check is unnecessary because I am already checking the token length. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: hmm, seems we are skip that the last one is unnecessary too(seems my previous example shows it to. Just print all non empty will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You're repeating the capturing group. This means that you'll only catch the last letter between `&`s in the group.
2. You will only match the last word because the `.*`s will gobble up the rest of the string.

Use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead:

```
(?<=&)[^&]+(?=&)
```

Now the entire match will be `hello` (and `bye` when you apply the regex for the second time) because the surrounding `&`s won't be part of the match any more:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=&)[^&]+(?=&)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding `.*` don't make sense and are unproductive.  Just `&([^&])*&` is sufficient.

Comment: No, it isn't. Capturing group 1 will contain `o` (for the first match) instead of `hello` and `e` (for the second match) instead of `bye`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes that should be `([^&]*)` instead, but I was just thinking of using the whole group (which would also remove the need to capture to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it even further.

1. Check that the first char is `&`
2. Check that the last char is `&`
3. `String.split("&&")` on the substring between them

In code:

```
if (string.length < 2)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(string); // or return[], whatever
if ( (string.charAt(0) != '&') || (string.charAt(string.length()-1) != '&')
    // handle this, too
String inner = string.substring(1, string.length()-1);
return inner.split("&&");
```